# How to implement the XY Heisenberg interaction using IBMQ and Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

A possible way to implement the 2 qubit Heisenberg XYZ model using a Quantum computer is to decompose the Hamiltonian as follows: $$H_{XYZ} = H_{XY} + H_{YZ} + H_{XZ}$$. In this case, these operators commute so we can apply the trotter formula to get the unitary evolution $$U = e^{-iH_{XY}t}e^{-iH_{XZ}t}e^{-iH_{YZ}t}$$

Further, using appropriate rotations on the single qubits, $H_{XZ}$ and $H_{YZ}$ can be expressed using single qubit gates and $H_{XY}$, meaning that the evolution $U$ should be able to be simulated using only single qubit rotations and the XY interaction ($H_{XY} = \sigma_1^X\sigma_2^X + \sigma_1^Y\sigma_2^Y$)

Given this, how can the XY interaction be implemented in IBMQ/Qiskit? Preferably it would be good to be able to do this without the use of an ancillary qubit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's use the fact that $\sigma^X_1 \sigma^X_2$ and $\sigma^Y_1 \sigma^Y_2$ commute. This means

$$e^{-i H_{XY} t} = e^{-i ~\sigma^X_1 \sigma^X_2~ t} ~ e^{-i ~\sigma^Y_1 \sigma^Y_2~ t}$$

Using appropriate single qubit rotations, $e^{-i ~\sigma^Y_1 \sigma^Y_2~ t}$ can be expressed using $e^{-i ~\sigma^X_1 \sigma^X_2~ t}$. So now we've reduced the problem to simply implementing $e^{-i ~\sigma^X_1 \sigma^X_2~ t}$.

To do this, the important relation to note is that,

$${CX}_{j,k} ~ e^{-i~\sigma^X_j~t} ~ {CX}_{j,k} = e^{-i ~\sigma^X_j \sigma^X_k~t}$$.

So all you need is a couple of cnots, and an appropriate single qubit rotation $e^{-i~\sigma^X_j~t}$ implemented on their control qubit. In Qiskit code, here's a two qubit circuit that would implement this (here I named the qubits as $0$ and $1$ instead of $1$ and $2$, to reflect the Python indexing convention)

```
    qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
    qc.cx(0,1)
    qc.rx(t,0)
    qc.cx(0,1)
```

Following this method would mean using 12 cnots to implement the whole Hamiltonian, which is quite a lot given the fidelities of current devices. Fancier methods are doubtless possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $\sigma_1^X\sigma_2^X$ and $\sigma_1^Y\sigma_2^Y$ commute, you can split the term into a product of two rotations.

$e^{t\cdot\sigma_1^X\sigma_2^X}$ can be understood as rotation along the $\{||00\rangle, |11\rangle \}$ basis. There are inbuilt gates to perform this rotation which decompose into the gates that James above has answered.
For example, [`RXX`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RXXGate.html), [`RYY`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RYYGate.html) gate can be used for what you desired:

```
t = 1.0
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.rxx(t, 0, 1)
circuit.ryy(t, 0, 1)
```

You can use the Trotterization of higher orders to achieve a more accurate approximation at a cost of gate complexity for any general Hamiltonian Simulation without any extra ancilla qubits.

If you want to perform arbitrarily rotations for any number of qubits, then you can use [`PauliEvolutionGate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PauliEvolutionGate.html) (Refer to my [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25972/how-to-do-rotations-along-arbitrary-multi-qubit-basis))