# How to do rotations along arbitrary multi-qubit basis

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation, trotterization

I was trying to implement Trotterization for a $k$-local Hamiltonian simulation using qiskit. For this, say I want to apply $e^{\lambda \sigma^1_z \otimes \sigma^2_z \otimes \sigma^3_z}$ (this being the 3-local case)

qiskit has support for rotations such as RXX, RYY, RZX, and so on that would be useful to apply the 2-local gates.

*How do I generalize this to a higher number of local interactions **without** using ancilla qubits?* ([this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/rotation-of-multi-body-interaction-in-quantum-circuit) answer is with an extra qubit)

Just in case I checked the source code of qiskit for RZZ, but it seems to be hardcoded without any general form.

*Is there a way to construct this, or is there something inbuilt in qiskit that I'm missing?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is by using [`PauliEvolutionGate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PauliEvolutionGate.html):

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import PauliEvolutionGate
from qiskit.opflow import Z

op = Z^Z^Z
_time = 1.0

# For the parameterized version:
# _time = Parameter('λ')

_gate = PauliEvolutionGate(op, time = _time, synthesis = None)

circ = QuantumCircuit(3)
circ.append(_gate, [0, 1, 2])
```

The third parameter passed to `PauliEvolutionGate` constructor, `synthesis`, can be used to specify the synthesis strategy.

By default it uses Lie-Trotter product formula ([`LieTrotter`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.synthesis.LieTrotter.html) class). Higher order Suzuki-Trotter product formula ([`SuzukiTrotter`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.synthesis.SuzukiTrotter.html) class) and matrix exponentiation ([`MatrixExponential`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.synthesis.MatrixExponential.html) class) can also be used.